# The meaning of synonym in typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

The following paragraph is taken from [dcl.typedef]:

> Within the scope of its declaration, a typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in the way described in Clause 8. A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type. A typedef-name does not introduce a new type the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does.

The other relevant passage we need is from [dcl.type]

> As a general rule, at most one type-specifier is allowed in the complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration or in a type-specifier-seq or trailing-type-specifier-seq. The only exceptions to this rule are the following: … long can be combined with long.

In the following code, `i1` is just a synonym for long.

```
typedef long i1;
typedef long i1 i2;
```

Thus, I expect the second line to be understood as `typedef long long i2`. However, MSVC2015RC fails with

> Error C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'i2'

Can anyone point to the part of the standard that invalidates my expectation?

---

UPDATE

My point is that, as far as I understand the grammar in [dcl.type],

```
type-specifier:
    trailing-type-specifier
    class-specifier
    enum-specifier
trailing-type-specifier:
    simple-type-specifier
    elaborated-type-specifier
    typename-specifier
    cv-qualifier
type-specifier-seq:
    type-specifier attribute-specifier-seq opt
    type-specifier type-specifier-seq
trailing-type-specifier-seq:
    trailing-type-specifier attribute-specifier-seq opt
    trailing-type-specifier trailing-type-specifier-seq
```

a decl-specifier-seq does allow for a sequence of type specifiers as long as they satisfy the combination rules. It seems to me that a type is not the same as a type-specifier even though a type is specified by a type specifier ;-)

Comment: In `long long` the first `long` is not a *qualifier* or *adjective* for the second one.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: nor it should be. I think that both `long` in `long long` are type-specifiers. The second quoted paragraph suggests me so.

Comment: @Hector In your example, `i1` is not syntactically equivalent to `long`. It is a synonym, but not a macro.

Comment: One rule that applies here is [dcl.type]p2 *"As a general rule, at most one type-specifier is allowed in the complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration or
in a type-specifier-seq or trailing-type-specifier-seq. The only exceptions to this rule are the following: [list of exceptions]"* See also [dcl.type.simple]p2.

Comment: @AlchemicalApples: The first quote begins with "a typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword". I would interpret that as "i1 is syntactically equivalent to the keyword long".

Comment: @Hector I don't believe that's how that section is supposed to be interpreted. The phrase, "syntactically equivalent to a keyword," just means that the typedef-name can be used in the same way that a keyword can. Assuming that `i1` can be used in place of `long` simply because they both act like keywords is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @AlchemicalApples I sort of see Hector's point though. If it can't be used the same way `long` can, which keyword *is* it supposed to be syntactically equivalent to? (The compiler is right to reject this, but the standard is very confusing here.)

Comment: @AlchemicalApples: Thus the title of this post. How much can we stretch the "synonym" part.

Comment: @hvd It belongs to the "keyword" syntactical category - it's not syntactically equivalent to any particular keyword but to all of them.

Comment: @Hector `i1` is a synonym for the *type* that is `long int`. It is not a synonym for the *keyword* `long`. Otherwise you could also say `i1 double` and get a `long double`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Pretty much the only thing specified for all keywords as a whole is that you can't use a keyword as an identifier. And that one thing is something that *doesn't* apply to a `typedef`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I'll answer.

First, looking at this:

> a typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword

This only means that typedef-names follow the syntax of keywords. This does not mean that a typedef-name is equivalent to any particular keyword. It's like a new, unique keyword.

Then we have,

> A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type.

So, given `typedef long i1;`, what is this "another type"? It is `long int`, not just `long`.

In addition, what is a "type"? At the least, type-specifier is not a type. The type-specifier `long` represents the type "long int" (see Table 10 of n3337 or Table 9 of n4296).

I'll copy my comment here:

> `i1` is a synonym for the *type* that is `long int`. It is not a synonym for the *keyword* `long`. Otherwise you could also say `i1 double` and get a `long double`.

Though perhaps I should have said, `i1` is not a synonym for the *type-specifier* `long`, but it is a synonym for the *type* `long int`.

Comment: The part that threw me off was "A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type." I read that as "A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type-specifier." Since type-specifiers can be linked into a type-specifier-seq, the question seemed natural.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no syntax rule which tells that `long` *`T`* is a valid type once *`T`* is a valid type. (But there is some related rule for  *qualifiers* like `volatile` or `const`)

In other words `long long` should *almost* be seen as a "multi-word keyword" (but the C & C++ standardization committees are very reluctant to introduce new keywords).

Hence, I don't expect the following to be valid

```
 // probably invalid
 typedef int fooT;
 unsigned fooT barv;
```

Comment: I understand your point, however the question is why it is not allowed.

Comment: Because no rule is allowing what you want.

Comment: Actually, the grammar for type-specifiers seemed to allow it. If the correspondence between type-specifiers and types was bijective, then there was no point in making the distinction between those two. Table 9 in [dcl.type.simple] shows that we can map from type-specifiers to types but no viceversa. Hence, the grammar for type-specifiers is not a grammar for types.

Answer (score 1):

Paragraph 2 of **[dcl.type]** has the rules for `long`, `short`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `const` and `volatile`.

> As a general rule, at most one type-speciﬁer is allowed in the complete decl-speciﬁer-seq of a declaration or in a type-speciﬁer-seq or trailing-type-speciﬁer-seq. The only exceptions to this rule are the following:
>
> - const can be combined with any type speciﬁer except itself.
> - volatile can be combined with any type speciﬁer except itself.
> - signed or unsigned can be combined with char, long, short, or int.
> - short or long can be combined with int.
> - long can be combined with double.
> - long can be combined with long.

Thus

```
typedef long i1;
typedef const i1 i2;
```

is valid since `const` can be combined with any type specifier while

```
typedef long i1;
typedef long i1 i2;
```

is not since `i1` is a name for `long` but it is not the specifier `long` itself.

`i1` in your example may syntactically be equivalent to a keyword but it is not among the allowed specifiers to be combined with `long`. It is a different keyword and thus the rule for combination with `long` does not apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to note the purpose of introducing the notion of synonym.
Synonyms were added to C to address auto-reference when defining structures.
For instance when defining a structure type used to represent an element in a linked list, you may want to define it as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int                     some_data; ///< ...or anything
    linked_list_element_t*  previous_element;
    linked_list_element_t*  next_element;
} linked_list_element_t;
```

The problem is of course the type "linked_list_element_t" is only defined *after* the typedef struct statement and can therefore not be used *within* the typedef struct statement.
You could of course use the generic void* pointer but that's not good practice and the previous_element and next_element members could be initialized to point to just anything.

You need to refer to the type from within the type definition. Enters the synonym:

```
typedef struct lle_t {
    int     some_data;
    lle_t*  previous_element;
    lle_t*  next_element;
} linked_list_element_t;
```

In this cheesy example the code would henceforth only use linked_list_element_t to refer to the type.